# How can I shift the current line to the middle of the screen?

Tags: notepad++

Sometimes when I'm on a line of text at the top or bottom of the buffer, I want to shift the buffer so that the current line is displayed in the middle of the screen. *I don't want to change any text*, just the *view* of the text buffer so that it's easier to see the current line.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold down the Control (CTRL) key while pressing the up or down arrows.

Comment: This shifts the whole buffer up or down a line, but doesn't center the buffer in the window. However, it solves my use case, which is usually to process a line in a macro and move to the next line. If I just Ctrl+Up at the end of processing the line, this has the desired effect of keeping the current line in the middle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution that will help you scroll up and
down and keep the cursor in center of screen if
already in center of screen:

1. Macro --> Start Recording
2. Press: UpArrowKey
3. Press: CTRL+UpArrowKey
4. Macro --> Stop Recording
5. Macro --> Save Current Recorded Macro
6. Settings --> Shortcut Mapper --> Macros

   I assigned mine to "pageup" and "pagedown" keys.
   For other direction, repeat steps, but use DownArrow.